# format datetime value from deserialized json object

Tags: c#, json

I have the following simplified JSON

```json
{
  "campaignId": 73,
  "count": 2,
  "eventTime": "2024-03-12T12:43:11.036"
}
```

And the following class object

```cs
public class Opened
{
    public int campaignId { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public DateTime eventTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime eventTimeNoMS()
    {
        return Convert.ToDateTime(eventTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

I deserialize via `System.text.json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize`.

I only ever want the datetime without the milliseconds. I feel like there is a better way to express this. I also have this format in another 20 locations. So I guess what would be even better is if there is a way to have a custom DateTime object if that is possible?

Comment: What is your problem with `Datetime` ??  You can choose [date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) without problem!

Comment: I don't have a problem with it.  I's just I'd like to hide away the formatting of the datetime and essentially do it in only one spot, if possible.  Otherwise I have lots of places where I am writing out to logs, etc where I don't want the ms.  So all of those places will all need .todatetimeformat.

Comment: What about hide this formatting in other string property `public string eventTimeString => eventTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");` and when you need application standard format call this property? Your method `eventTimeNoMS()` has no advantages because it still returns `DateTime` which is still formatable object did not different from of using `eventTime` itself

Comment: is it better to change type from DateTime to string and store in format you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since type of property is a DateTime - not much you can do - it will use system datetime settings. but you can add additional string field to convert to format you want.
or you can do as extension to use everywhere
is it what you want?

```
void Main()
{
    string j = "{\"campaignId\": 73,\"count\": 2,\"eventTime\": \"2024-03-12T12:43:11.036\"}";
    var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Opened>(j).Dump();
    
    o.eventTime.ToString().Dump();
    o.eventTime.ToCustomString().Dump(); //custom string
}

public class Opened
{
    public int campaignId { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public DateTime eventTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime eventTimeNoMS
    {
        get { return Convert.ToDateTime(eventTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")); }
    }
    public string eventTimeString
    {
        get { return eventTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt"); }
    }
}

public static class Ext { 
    public static string ToCustomString(this DateTime dt){
        return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff tt--"); //remove :fff if you dont need milliiseconds
    }
    
}
```

[image]